# python selenium Chrome Web Driver. How to Proxy IP/ Where to buy

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, webdriver, vpn

So i want to make Selenium Project where I  need to change my ip to to a specific Cities.For example one in Dallas, One in NewYork, One in Los Angles.

I wanted to know how do I apply a proxy to the chrome web driver using PYTHON.
If you guys can show me an example code that would be very helpful. I have seen others with Firefox web driver but not the chrome web Driver.

Also where can i buy a Dedicated IP PROXY for each city. I want to be the only one using that ip Address.

Answer (score 4):

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=1.2.3.4:8080')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get("...")
```

Comment: What we should use in place of 1.2.3.4, I mean where from we get this IP